# "unsafeMutableAddressor : Swift.String", referenced from:.."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, ui-testing

I got an error:

> `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "DirectBistro.DBTabBarOrderedIndexesKey.unsafeMutableAddressor : Swift.String", referenced from:
>         DirectBistroUITests.TabBarControllerTests.setUp (DirectBistroUITests.TabBarControllerTests)() -> () in TabBarControllerTests.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

This is my simple `UITest` class:

```
import XCTest
@testable import DirectBistro

class TabBarControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject([], forKey: DBTabBarOrderedIndexesKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

This is how it is defined in `DBTabBarController.swift`:

```
let DBTabBarOrderedIndexesKey = "TabBarOrderedIndexesKey"
```

**Info** pane:

[image]

**General** pane:

[image]

Comment: Have you set the host app for your tests properly?

Comment: Host app for tests? How to do this?

Comment: Goto your target settings, select the test target>Info

Comment: I updated the question with screen you mentioned, is it ok?

Comment: Can you show the 'general' pane?

Comment: General pane is shown, there is I think a proper target application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87132/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-nshebbar).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The conslusion is: **it is not going to work**.

I report it as a bug to Apple, and got a response:

> UI tests execute differently from Unit tests - Unit tests run inside your application process so they can access your application code. UI tests execute in a separate process, outside your application, so they can simulate how the user interacts with the application. It’s not expected that you will be able to access your app class from a UI test.

Comment: can you share a link of apple reply?

Answer (score 7):

It **is** possible to access application code from your UI tests. Just add the source file to the UI test target:

[image]

You can then access that application code from within your UI test code:

[image]

But bear in mind that the application code you're accessing thus from your UI Test is code running *in your UI Test target* (MyAppUITests), it does not correspond to the code running in the actual app target (MyApp). So do not use it to inspect or modify application state.

Comment: I have an SDK that I use in my app using cocoa pods. How would I access the SDK code from the UI Test target?

Comment: @ShakedSayag In your Podfile, add the SDK's pod to your main target *and* to the UI Test target (under `target 'MyAppUITests'`) as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I added my swift package and tried to use a string variable inside it. The fix is just to add the swift package in the frameworks, libraries section in the target General section[image]

Answer (score 0):

I received similar error while running test case. I identified that there were certain string values being referred in my test case from another file in the main iOS app project. They couldn't be accessed here.
I solved it by creating a local constant in my test case method. You may please suggest a better way.