# Can't figure out the number of Xcode crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode

I have three crash reports in the Xcode Organizer Crashes tab.

> APC2: appSettings.unsafeMutableAddressor + 44
>
> 1 device
>
> APC2: appSettings.unsafeMutableAddressor + 56
>
> 1 device
>
> libswiftCore.dylib: specialized _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, >StaticString, UInt) -> () + 164
>
> 1 device

My questions:

1. What do the numbers after the plus mean?

2. In iTunes Connect app analytics I'm seeing 31 crashes, but in Xcode Organizer Crashes tab I'm seeing the above.
3. What is this `unsafeMutableAddressor` error? Strangely I can't find anything related to this error.

Comment: May be a bug to Apple. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043920/unsafemutableaddressor-swift-string-referenced-from